# Function Shape Reference

Tags: soft-question, reference-request, functions, functional-equations

I'm wondering if their exists a visual/behavioral reference for the fundamental families of functions. I'm not a mathematician so excuse my language if I'm being overly vague.

I would like to have a reference where I can go look at images of functions and say: that looks like a behavior/character I want. Or maybe even search on the properties of the function, such as it's periodic, or that the output is always in the [-1, 1] range.

Comment: There are books which contain tables of functions, often accompanied with plots. [Abrahamowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/) is a well-known one. They are a bit of relics of the pre-computer era.

Comment: When you say cyclic do you mean periodic?

Comment: Yep periodic is the word I meant.

Comment: see if wolframalpha helps?

Comment: Problem with wolframalpha is you need to know what to call the function :)